# Killing vectors to derive conservation laws

Tags: general-relativity, differentiation

$X^{\mu}(s)$ is a geodesic and $\xi$ is Killing and $u^{\mu}=\dot{X}^{\mu}$, $s$ proper time

$$\frac{d}{ds}\left(k^{\mu}\xi_{\mu}\right)=u^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}{\left(k^{\mu}\xi_{\mu}\right)}=u^{\nu}D_{\nu}{\left(k^{\mu}\xi_{\mu}\right)}$$

My question is: what is the reason/rule for replacing the partial derivative with covariant derivative? Why are they the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quantity in parentheses is a scalar. On scalar quantities the covariant derivative reduces to the partial derivative. Inversely, a partial derivative on a scalar can always be replaced by a covariant derivative.